# Automatic keyboard backlight

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

is it possible to turn on keyboard backlight automatically depending on hour? 
Now if I want to enable backlight on keyboard I need to press some keys combinations. It would be wonderfull to do that automatically - like f.lux changing display brightness...
I have HP Envy DV7.
My OS is Windows 8.1

Comment: If it is not an option of the software provided by HP then it would be extremely difficult to achieve this.  The best you could do is write software that runs in the background that the keyboard shortcut at the appropriate time of day.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretially, you can create such a software if you have partnered with a manufacturer (HP, Lenovo, etc.), then they give you API's to control features of their hardware. But in practice I can't see nearly any 3rd party programs for these PCs.

How I'm solving this: I'm including quality of utilities added by manufacturer into my puchasing decision. So not only CPU power and RAM size matters when deciding for new laptop :) Usually you have to spend your computer lifetime with these tools, expect no further upgrades or enhancements.

So NO, most likely there isn't possibility of backlight changes if it was not supplied in one of manufacturer utilities.